# Standalone Executable Created by PyInstaller Can't Import Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, exe, pyinstaller

I'm trying to make a standalone executable file of a GUI application using Python, and am running into a very strange error that prevents the program from running. The only version of Python on my machine using Windows10 is 3.7.2. When I launch the program from the command line it works perfectly and I don't encounter any problems. However, when I create a standalone executable file using pyinstaller, I get the "Failed to execute script" error. After some troubleshooting, and looking at the errors coming from the terminal, I realized that the error is coming from the use of numpy in my program. The error that results in the script failing to execute reads: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named'numpy.core._dtype_ctypes'".

However, when I run python and type command 'import numpy' in my terminal, I don't encounter any problems with this module. What might explain this strange error that I encounter? I've tried uninstalling and re-installing numpy, but this hasn't worked. I've also double-checked to make sure that I'm not accidently using a previously installed version of Python that doesn't have numpy installed. I haven't been able to come up with any reasons that this might happen.

Any insights to why this weird problem might be happening?

Comment: I've run into similar with MatPlotLib. Check out this to start: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3982

Comment: Try manually importing the package into the script. Use "import numpy.core._dtype_ctypes" in your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran across the same problem.  This is a known issue with numpy 1.16.0.  As a temporary fix I reverted back to numpy 1.15.4.